# Is character a countable or an uncountable noun?

Tags: nouns

Is character a countable or uncountable noun? How to judge?

Comment: It can be both. You just have to look in a dictionary, making sure that you have identified the sense in which it is being used.

Comment: Are you talking about the graphic symbol, or the personal attribute, or the person in a drama or novel? Please also explain what research you've already done. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: It's far more reasonable to talk about count(able) or non-count **usages**.

Answer (score 3):

Both depending on the meaning being conveyed.

(*countable*) A character as a person in a story, movie, play, etc.

(*uncountable*) Character as the combination of personal qualities.